# Get the state of child checkbox in checkbox tree

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have checkboxes in tree structure.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXfSP.png)

Issue: When I click on Super checkbox I want the state of all it's child checkboxes(Sub checkboxes). Using this state I can enable/disable the corresponding buttons besides these sub checkboxes.

For some security reason I cannot post the script but can share he HTML

CODE:

```css
.section{flow:horizontal;margin-left:25px;}
.leftText{width:100px;}
```

```html
<div class="superWrapper">
 <div class="super" id="CheckbBox1">
  <input type="checkbox"  class="testCheck" name="Checkbox" id="Checkbox01" value=true checked />
  <label for="Checkbox01">Super1</label>
 </div>
 <div class="wrapper" id="wrapper1">
  <div class="section" id="subtext1" >
   <div class="leftText" id="check1" >
    <input type="checkbox" name="name1" id="Checkbox01_1" />
    <label for="Checkbox01_1"><span>Sub 1</span></label>
   </div>
   <div class="rightBtn">
    <button class="BtnNrm">Button 1</button>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="section" id="subtext2" >
   <div class="leftText" id="check2" >
    <input type="checkbox" name="name2" id="Checkbox01_2" />
    <label for="Checkbox01_2"><span>Sub 2</span></label>
   </div>
   <div class="rightBtn">
    <button class="BtnNrm">Button 2</button>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section" id="subtext3" >
   <div class="leftText" id="check3" >
    <input type="checkbox" name="name3" id="Checkbox01_3" />
    <label for="Checkbox01_3"><span>Sub 3</span></label>
   </div>
   <div class="rightBtn">
    <button class="BtnNrm" >Button 3</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <!-- Check box 2 -->
 <div class="super" id="CheckbBox2" >
  <input type="checkbox"  class="testCheck" name="Checkbox" id="Checkbox02" value=true checked />
  <label for="Checkbox02">Super2</label>
 </div>
 <div class="wrapper" id="wrapper2">
  <div class="section" id="subtext4" >
   <div class="leftText" id="check4" >
    <input type="checkbox" name="name4" id="Checkbox02_1" />
    <label for="Checkbox02_1"><span>Sub 4</span></label>
   </div>
   <div class="rightBtn">
    <button class="BtnNrm">Button 1</button>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div  class="section" id="subtext5" >
   <div class="leftText" id="check5" >
    <input type="checkbox" name="name5" id="Checkbox02_2" />
    <label for="Checkbox02_2"><span>Sub 5</span></label>
   </div>
   <div class="rightBtn">
    <button class="BtnNrm">Button 2</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Any help?

Comment: JQuery is not an option ?

Comment: jQuery is not needed here.